# How to pass a checkbox value from one iframe to another iframe

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I have two iframes (let say iframe A and B). Iframe A displays a table where the first column contains checkbox. Whenever user marks the checkbox, I want the value in that checkbox to be passed to pageB in iframeB.Part of the code for my checkbox is given below. I would appreciate any help given. Thanks

```
<tr>
<td class='am'>
<form action='pageB.php' method='post' target='iframe-pageB'  id='pageA'>
<input name='checkselect' type='checkbox' value='$first_string|$second_string'>$combined_string</input>
</form>
</td>
```

Comment: Parent windows have access to iframe DOM structures (and vice versa), so you could set element values like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the second iframe using:

```
var iframe2 = parent.document.getElementById('iframe2');
```

And then the subsequent elements can be referenced by:

```
var doc = iframe2.contentDocument? iframe2.contentDocument: iframe2.contentWindow.document;
// reference to display text box
var field = doc.forms['iframe2DemoForm'].elements['display'];
```

[This should help](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/refs/iframe-iframe.php)